# Dependiendo del servidor me devuelve el error Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, select

Tengo una consulta que me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
Warning: mysqli_query(): (21000/1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row in /usr/home/..........
```

Este es el query:

```
  SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS p.*, 
    (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta pm WHERE pm.post_id = p.ID AND meta_key = 'localidad') AS 'localidad', 
    (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta pm WHERE pm.post_id = p.ID AND meta_key = 'direccion') AS 'direccion', 
    (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta pm WHERE pm.post_id = p.ID AND meta_key = 'c.p.') AS 'cp', 
    (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta pm WHERE pm.post_id = p.ID AND meta_key = 'codigo') AS 'codigo', 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.name SEPARATOR ';') FROM wp_terms t, wp_term_taxonomy tx, wp_term_relationships tr   
        WHERE t.term_id = tx.term_id AND tx.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id AND tr.object_id = p.ID AND tx.taxonomy = 'gama' ORDER BY tx.term_taxonomy_id) AS 'gama', 
    (SELECT t.name FROM wp_terms t, wp_term_taxonomy tx, wp_term_relationships tr 
        WHERE t.term_id = tx.term_id AND tx.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id AND tr.object_id = p.ID AND tx.taxonomy = 'pais' ORDER BY tx.term_taxonomy_id) AS 'pais', 
    (SELECT t.term_id FROM wp_terms t, wp_term_taxonomy tx, wp_term_relationships tr 
        WHERE t.term_id = tx.term_id AND tx.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id AND tr.object_id = p.ID AND tx.taxonomy = 'pais' ORDER BY tx.term_taxonomy_id) AS 'id_pais', 
    (SELECT t.name FROM wp_terms t, wp_term_taxonomy tx, wp_term_relationships tr 
        WHERE t.term_id = tx.term_id AND tx.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id AND tr.object_id = p.ID AND tx.taxonomy = 'provincia' ORDER BY tx.term_taxonomy_id) AS 'provincia', 
    (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta pm 
        WHERE pm.post_id = p.ID AND meta_key = 'localizacion') AS 'localizacion' 
FROM wp_posts p 
WHERE 1=1 AND p.post_type = 'distribuidor' AND (p.post_status = 'publish' OR p.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR p.post_status = 'private') 
ORDER BY p.post_title ASC
```

He conseguido que me funcione en un par de servidores, pero en el que necesito alojarlo es el que me devuelve el error mencionado.

¿Alguien sabe si hay alguna configuración que se pueda cambiar en el servidor para que no devuelva error o alguna otra forma de hacer el query?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he podido resolver añadiendo LIMIT 1 a todos los subqueries

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70925303/only-in-my-server-returns-subquery-returns-more-than-1-row

Comment: Si, sirve, pero ojo, porque entonces estas trayendo un dato aleatorio de una tabla que no sabes cual es, y puede llegar a traer otra cosa en otro momento. En realidad deberias ver cual de los querys trae mas de una fila, porque lo hace, y verificar si no tenes mal tu base de datos. Si realmente sirve el limit, entonces directamente tus datos estan mal o estas trayendo algo que no necesitas.

Comment: Tienes razón, he revisado los valores que devuelve y hay diferencias respecto cómo deberían ser.

Comment: Igual, tu respuesta es mala, porque es solo un enlace sin ninguna explicacion. Tenes que probar 1 a 1 los querys, para ver cual trae mas de una fila. No es algo que podamos hacer nosotros.